# CMake - How to get include directories of external project?

Tags: cmake

I tried to used https://github.com/julianxhokaxhiu/SteamworksSDKCI to use steam api on a simple SFML application (helloworld).
I wanted to use cmake to learn it, but I am struggling to understand how the provided CMakeLists and Find*.cmake file are expected to be used.

Currently, I have modified the CMakeLists to change the INSTALL_DIR

```
INSTALL_DIR     "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../../vendor"
```

and my CMakeLists is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(SfmlWithCMake VERSION 1.0)

include(FetchContent)
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH};${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_steam")

# Configure external project
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_steam)
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_steam
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_steam
)

# Build external project
execute_process(
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_steam
)

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
FetchContent_Declare(
 SFML
 GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SFML/SFML.git
 GIT_TAG 2.5.1
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SFML)

find_package(STEAMWORKSSDK REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED true)

# Generate config.h
configure_file(config.h.in config.h)

add_executable(
 SfmlWithCMake
 main.cpp
)

get_target_property(STEAMSDK STEAMWORKSSDK::STEAMWORKSSDK INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)

target_include_directories(
  SfmlWithCMake 
  PRIVATE
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}"
   "${STEAMSDK}"
  )

target_link_libraries(
 SfmlWithCMake
 sfml-graphics
 STEAMWORKSSDK::STEAMWORKSSDK
 -static gcc stdc++ winpthread -dynamic 
)

install(TARGETS SfmlWithCMake DESTINATION bin)
```

1. How to get include directories?

I do not succeed to add the steam include to the target_include_directories.
Here the ${STEAMSDK} is my last attempt to get the directory.

If I replace this by ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/vendor/include, everything works.

Also, why does the SFML include are automatically added to my target include directories and not the steam one?

2. Am I using the Find*.cmake file the right way?

I understood that ExternalProject_Add was performed at build time and thus, as the find_package is needed at configue time, I added the two "execute_process". But, the readme on github only says to do the find package and add the target to target_link_libraries...

Thanks.

Comment: I would be helpful if you shared the output from CMake and/or the error your application prints to the terminal after it fails.

Comment: There's no need for `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to be a single element. I'm not even sure, if cmake is able to deal with multiple paths combined to a single varible. Just use this as a list variable: `list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_steam)` or `set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_steam)`